# Jmeter - Sending request data from csv files with a time interval

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have 1000 records in a csv file. I want to send all the records/data with packets of 50 records (all different) per minute in jmeter. Please guide me the Jmeter configuration for this.
flow-1-50 in 1 minute, then 50-100 in 2nd minute, then 100-150 in 3rd minute.....950-1000 in 20th minute

Comment: how many threads are you planning to use?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to send 50 records per minute evenly distributed like 0.83 requests per second - go for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
2. If you want to send 50 records in one shot then wait for 1 minute then send next 50 - go for [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) and [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler

Records from CSV can be retrieved using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)